# Should i use Join or use seperate queries

Tags: php, mysql, join

```
Table 1: book(bookid(pk),bookname,edition)
Table 2: bookinfoauthors(bookid(fk), authorid(fk))
Table 3: author(authorid(pk), authorname)
```

I have a array of AuthorNames I want to get the corresponding bookName written by those authors
AuthorNames might contain 1 or more names

I am using php and mysql Database

Style 1:

```
select book.bookName
from book, bookauthors, author
where  (book.bookid = bookoauthors.bookid)
and (author.authorid = bookauthor.authorid)
and (author.authorName = Authornames[0])
or (author.authorName = Authornames[1])
or (author.authorName = Authornames[2])
or (author.authorName = Authornames[3])
```

As i am using php my mysql;
Style 2:
        // suppose $authorId, $bookId, $bookName contains array of int or string not objects

```
$authorId  = 
    select authorId
    from authors
    where authorName in ($authorNames);

$bookId = select bookid from bookAuthors where bookName in($authorId);
$bookName = select bookName from book where bookid in (bookId);
```

In second style I am not using joins which one will be efficient and what should I follow

Comment: use joins.. it is fast then normal queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would say that you almost certainly would rather do a single `JOIN` query to get a single result set than making many different calls to your MySQL database.  MySQL was designed for heavy lifting of data; PHP much less so.  The time spent in network traffic could be substantial in the latter case, impacting the performance of your site.

Second you should try to use ANSI-92 compliant SQL queries.  So I would rewrite your `JOIN` query as this:

```
SELECT b.bookName
FROM book b INNER JOIN bookauthors ba ON b.bookid = ba.bookid
            INNER JOIN author a ON a.authorid = ba.authorid
WHERE a.authorName = Authornames[0] OR
      a.authorName = Authornames[1] OR
      a.authorName = Authornames[2] OR
      a.authorName = Authornames[3]
```

The reason this style of query is preferred is that it separates the joining of tables from the other restrictions in the `WHERE` clause.  In your original query the join criteria and restrictions both appear together in the `WHERE` clause making it harder to read.

Comment: Thanks i really thought the second one would be better